# Would this function be allowed in Swift (if it wouldn't crash the compiler)

Tags: swift

I got this function, which is a minimised version of an actual use case:

```
func f (i:Int) -> <T> (x:T) -> T {
    return { x in return x }
}
```

As you see I would like to compute a generic function based on some input.
But as you can see in Xcode or on [swiftstub](http://swiftstub.com/869923664/), this function crashes the compiler.
Does anybody know if Swift is supposed to support such definitions?

Comment: It looks like Rank-1 polymorphism in Haskell. But in Swift 1.2, the compiler rejects your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This no longer crashes the compiler when I try it on 1.2b3.  However, it’s not valid syntax.

If you want to return a function where the type is determined up-front at the time `f` is called, this would do it:

```
func f<T>(i:Int) -> T -> T {
    return { x in return x }
}

// need to tell the compiler what T actually is...
let g = f(1) as Int->Int

g(2) // returns 2
```

However, Swift does not support the ability to define “generic” closures, i.e. closures where the type is determined not on creation of the closure, but at the point when that closure is actually called.  This would require higher-ranked polymorphism, something that isn’t currently available (though maybe in the future, who knows – would be a very nice feature to have).  For now, the placeholders need to be fully determined at the call site.

Comment: As usual, best to open a bug report /radar/ to speed things up.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the "generic" nature of Swift generics is kind of a misnomer. The genericness is just a template notation; all genericness is compiled away at compile time - that is, all generics used in one part of your code are resolved (specified) by the way they are called in another part of your code.

But for that very reason, you can't return a generic function as a result of a function, because there is no way to resolve the generic at compile time.

So, while crashing the compiler is not nice (and Apple would like to know about it), your code should not compile either, and to that extent the compiler is correct to resist.